# Monotouch 3.1.3 with iOS 4.2 install?

Tags: ios4, xamarin.ios, ios-4.2

How do I install iOS 4.2 so that MonoTouch 3.1.3 can target the iOS 4.2 Simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want Project->iPhone Simulator Target->iPad Simulator 4.2

Comment: is it safe to install the 4.2 SDK then with Monotouch 3.1.3?

Comment: I am using it but I am having an issue using device debugging.  Other than that it seems fine.